# How to run my Python Linked List in the console or Mac Terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, linked-list, pycharm, console

I am following a data structures and algorithms course and we have made the basis of a Linked List. In the course, the guy interacts with the code using the console using the following commands:

```
>>python -i nameoffile.py
>>N1 = Node (10)
>>N1
```

Which then displays

```
 < Node data: 10>
```

However, when I have tried this using the PyCharm console and Pycharm terminal/Mac terminal I get the error::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/code.py", line 63, in runsource
    code = self.compile(source, filename, symbol)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codeop.py", line 178, in __call__
    return _maybe_compile(self.compiler, source, filename, symbol)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codeop.py", line 106, in _maybe_compile
    raise err1
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codeop.py", line 93, in _maybe_compile
    code1 = compiler(source + "\n", filename, symbol)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codeop.py", line 143, in __call__
    codeob = compile(source, filename, symbol, self.flags, True)
  
File "<input>", line 1
    python -i LinkedListTest.py
              ^
```

This is the foundation of the linked list code I have been working with:

```
class Node:
    data = None
    next_data = None
def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data

def __repr__(self):
    return ' < Node data: %s' % self.data
```

When I try running the code through the terminal, as one of the comments suggested, using:

```
>>python -i nameoffile.py
>>N1 = Node (10)
>>N1
```

I get this error:

```
>>> N1 = Node(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Node() takes no arguments
```

I have checked through everything and the filenames are correct but I am confused as to why this is happening. Any help, please?

Comment: You need to run `python -i nameoffile.py` _in your terminal_. This opens an interpreter and the `nameoffile.py` file is run. Then it gives you control to enter your commands in the REPL

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. I have done that but get the error ( I will put it in the main problem): >>> N1 = Node(10)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Node() takes no arguments

Comment: The indentation of your class definition is off, as a consequence your class has no `__init__` method.

Comment: Does it need to be 1 TAB to the right?

Comment: you have create the same indentation as in other lines - if `data = None` has one TAB indentation then `def __init__(self, data):` needs also one TAB indentation. If `data = None` has 4 spaces then `def __init__(self, data):` needs also 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use the Terminal with the given code.
python -i nameoffile.py

In addition, to correcting the indentation. Thanks, StackOverflow!